# Set maximum of upload size in a asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

in asp.net I cant set my upload limit with the value:"maxAllowedContentLength". This value has the type uint32, that means it has a maximum size of: "4294967295". The problem is, that 4gb for me, are not enough. Is there a way, to increase this value?

Comment: What value do you want it to be?

Comment: I've to upload  files with a size of 10gb.

Comment: I'd imagine for that size you would need to have a js/flash based split async file uploader so you can split the files into more manageable chunks. Is there no option to use a different option as 10gb will also probably cause timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that increasing the size more than the range of int32 gives error in configuration settings.

However, if you must upload files with size larger than maximum than you might consider the possibility of splitting the files into smaller chunks and then transfer and store them on server and then creating a process to combine them when a user asks to download the file.

Comment: Okay , the only way I can go, is to splitt the file into smaller chuncks. Thanks!